# Spring kafka batch listener transaction

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-transactions

I am using spring kafka batch listener. For dealing with exception, I am throwing BatchListenerFailedException with the index of the failed msg. In the kafka config class, I have added this logic.

```
DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer dlpRecoverer = new DeadLetterPublish8ngRecoverer(dltTemplate,(record, exception) -> new TopicPartition(topicName, record.partition()));
DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(dlpRecoverer, new FixedBackOff(0,0));
factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);
```

After executing this logic, failed msg are getting pushed to dlt topic but offset is getting committed intermittently. Hence same msg batch is getting polled again.
Exception I am getting while commit.sync is
CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not a part of an active group for auto partition assignment.

Tried BatchExceptionHandling logic but did not work

Answer (score 0):

Your consumer is taking too long to process the batch and Kafka is kicking the consumer out of the group; either increase `max.poll.intervl.ms` or decrease `max.poll.records` such that your listener can always process the records without exceeding the interval (allow a good amount of safety).

Comment: Yeah I have already increased the interval to 90 sec and just 3 records but still I am getting that exception. And same batch is getting polled again

Comment: My requirement is.. after polling a batch, if any record is invalid then that record should be published in error topic and the offfset should be committed so that 
the next polled batch starts from the offset after the failed msg offset.

Comment: Another behavior I observed is when the offsets in toCommit and remaining are committed, still in the next batch, same messages are polled again which is not as expected

Comment: The title mentions transactions. You can’t use an error handler with transactions because it runs within the transaction. Use an after rollback processor instead. With transactions, the complete batch has to be redelivered.

Answer (score 0):

I am  throwing batchListenerFailedExcpetion with the index of the failed msg and using error handler which publishes the failed record( suppose 2nd msg) to error topic and commits the offset. In the rollbackprocessor logic, I have overriden the process method with no code inside the method since defaulterrorhandler does the required job. And in the next poll call, I can now see the message batch starting from the offset after the failed msg offset. But the problem is since I am using transaction in a batch, even if 1st msg of that batch is successfully commited in the error handler, but in the poll method, after processing and publishing of the msg to downstream topic corresponding to the first msg is done, It wont be available in that downstream topic since that particular txn is aborted and we are read8ng in read_committed mode

Comment: Hi, are you using MANUAL commits with the batch listener?

Comment: Yes manual commit